# Does the audittrail module of YII support concurrency on DB updates?

Tags: database, yii

I want to store the log of modifications made to a YII model.

I saw that there is a nice module called [audittrail](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/audittrail)  which uses the `afterSave` behavior that should do the trick, but I'm worried about how it will behave under high load of DB (i.e. high concurrency to the updates of the same rows of the DB).

Has anyone ever used this approach (either the `afterSave` or the module itself)? Will it cause me problems with concurrency?

Comment: +1 do ask this in the [yii forum](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/forum/29-general-discussion-for-yii-11x/) if you haven't already.